Python removesuffix doesn't work properly
I made a program that scrapes today's featured article from Wikipedia and prints it out:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    element = soup.find('div', {'id': 'mp-tfa'})
    output = element.p.get_text()

And if I add print(output) it prints out the article like this: '[insert article here] (Full article...)'
I tried to get rid of the text at the end by printing it like this: print(output.removesuffix(' (Full article...')) but that still doesn't get rid of it. Am I not using this function properly or do I have to use another method to remove it?

Any non-printable characters? Perhaps an ellipsis? Try looking at the final bytes perhaps.

Or just missing closing parenthesis in the argument...

That was a typo, I meant to type this: print(output.removesuffix(' (Full article...)'))

Well I'm on mobile so can't run your example but removesuffix works. Your string is not what you think it is.

How do I check the final bytes?

Nvm I checked the final bytes and there was a \xa0, updated it and it works

Using removesuffix() is right approach. However, the issue is you're missing the closing parenthesis for the string in your call to removesuffix().
Here's the updated code.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    element = soup.find('div', {'id': 'mp-tfa'})
    output = element.p.get_text()
    
    cleaned_output = output.removesuffix(' (Full article...)')
    print(cleaned_output)

I hope this will help you a little.
